# Authentication process in ARD

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, remote-desktop

I am working on a third party client for Apple Remote Desktop. But I am stuck on its authentication process.

From Remote Desktop manual:
    Authentication to Apple Remote Desktop clients uses an
    authentication method which is based on a Diffie-Hellman Key
    agreement protocol that creates a shared 128-bit key. This shared
    key is used to encrypt both the name and password using the Advanced
    Encryption Standard (AES). The Diffie-Hellman Key agreement protocol
    used in ARD 2 is very similar to the Diffie-Hellman Key agreement
    protocol used in personal file sharing, with both of them using a
    512-bit prime for the shared key calculation. With Remote Desktop 2,
    keystrokes and mouse events are encrypted when you control Mac OS X
    client computers. This information is encrypted using the Advanced
    Encryption Standard (AES) with the 128-bit shared key that was
    derived during authentication.

Does anyone know where I can find a bit more technical information about the Authentication process in ARD? Such as which AES mode it uses and what initialization vector. Thanks

Comment: I am having trouble with generating the ciphertext and dh public key. Do have objective-c code for the ARD authentication process? I'm trying to create an input only ARD client for a home theatre on an iOS.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work. I'm trying to figure this out myself, but I can't figure how to do this with Objective C. Do you have any code you can share? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this exact problem recently.  I couldn't find any detailed information beyond the high-level overview you mention, but I was able to figure out the technique based on my study of [this C code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk-vnc/commit/?id=416a0dc3592e831409e6e8c18929b785094ef87c) from the gtk-vnc open source project.  Basically, the steps are as follows:

1. Read the authentication material from the socket.  A two-byte generator value, a two-byte key length value, the prime modulus (keyLength bytes), and the peer's generated public key (keyLength bytes).
2. Generate your own Diffie-Hellman public-private key pair.
3. Perform Diffie-Hellman key agreement, using the generator (g), prime (p), and the peer's public key.  The output will be a shared secret known to both you and the peer.
4. Perform an MD5 hash of the shared secret.  This 128-bit (16-byte) value will be used as the AES key.
5. Pack the username and password into a 128-byte plaintext "credentials" structure: `{ username[64], password[64] }`.  Null-terminate each.  Fill the unused bytes with random characters so that the encryption output is less predictable.
6. Encrypt the plaintext credentials with the 128-bit MD5 hash from step 4, using the AES 128-bit symmetric cipher in electronic codebook (ECB) mode.  Use no further padding for this block cipher.
7. Write the ciphertext from step 6 to the stream.  Write your generated DH public key to the stream.
8. Check for authentication pass/fail as usual.

I don't have an Objective C implementation to share, but I have [implemented this Java version](https://github.com/simmons/valence/blob/f06b9f987cc6109d67b0f28f81e9ccd761f914fa/src/com/cafbit/valence/rfb/RFBSecurityARD.java) which you may find useful to reference.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone still needs this, but [here's a Objective C implementation](https://github.com/vwong2013/iOSVNCInputClient/blob/master/iOSVNCInputClient/RFB/RFBSecurityARD.m) of the ARD authentication process that I cobbled together a few months back and released on Github a few days ago.

It's based loosely on David's (thanks!) Java implementation but uses OpenSSL's encryption functions for the MD5 hashing and AES 128 encryption steps.

There's also the [TinyVNC](https://github.com/sergeystoma/tinyvnc) library that also implements ARD authentication, but using the Crypto++ library for encryption functions instead.